# Air circulation in a large/high room - are air circulators actually different than fans?

Tags: hvac, fans

Context:  I have a large open space (approx 40'x20', 22' high) with an unfortunately designed ducting system...  all the heating registers are at ceiling level.  There is an open mezzanine about 14' deep about halfway up - making it a full ground floor and partial, open second floor.  In the winter, the mezzanine reaches temps of 100F before the ground floor is a comfortable 72F.

I know the "correct" answer is a high-volume, low-speed (HVLS) ceiling fan.  But installing such a thing is expensive & difficult with a 22' ceiling.  And with all the lighting being in the ceiling, and a fan with a 6'+ wingspan, I'm concerned about turning the place into a discotheque.

After some experimentation, My DIY fix has been two 20" box fans, placed on 3' stands at ground level, pointing straight up.  It works o.k. - reducing the temp differential to ~10F - but I'm wondering if I can do better, power/noise-wise, with a different fan design.  Specifically, "air circulators" (e.g. Vornado).

I've read that via optimized blade/enclosure/grill design, air circulators produce more of a forceful, concentrated "column" of air, which circulates the room air more efficiently than a normal box/pedestal fan, for a given power/noise profile.  It does seem intuitive that vertical reach would improve my situation - making sure the temperature layers are mixing.

I've also read that this is total bullsh!t, and that only raw CFM matters.

Is there any truth to the claims about air circulators?  The ones I've looked at do seem to be quieter, lower power, lower CFM than my box fans.  But that could be a good thing, or it could just mean that they're equivalent to smaller box fans.

---

Note:  other high CFM solutions, such as those [fully-enclosed floor units](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001F5PNI8) used in construction for drying stuff, and the [high-velocity drum fans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09284PLTX) used in industrial applications, etc. don't seem feasible - because loud & power-hungry, even on the lowest settings.

Comment: Well, as an efficiency geek with a fan-soluble problem, "mixed flow axial" seem to be the winners on air moved .vs. power consumed. and doing it quietly. But I'd go ahead and connect them to a pipe/duct, whether pulling hot air down or pushing cold air up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is not about home improvement

Comment: Thanks for the comment - looking into mixed flow axial, they seem to be of the "industrial" variety...  large, power-hungry, and high CFM.  But my space already has a sort of industrial look, so hanging one of these near the ceiling might provide a reasonable alternative to a giant HVLS unit.

Still a significant project - scissor lift, building some sort of mounting armature, etc.  But maybe more feasible than HVLS.

In the short-term, I'm still looking for a DIY solution that has a better sound/power profile than box fans, that I can whip up with off-the-shelf fans.

Comment: As for how this isn't related to home improvement, I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm trying to improve my home.  I searched the physics and aviation stackexchange, but this diy one seemed most appropriate.  If you know of a better stackexchange subforum, I'm happy to cross-post.